# AttributeError: 'TestFiles' object has no attribute '_reports'

Tags: python, pytest

I've two class one is in my **test.py** and another one is in my **main.py** file named as `TestFiles` and `Files` respectively. My `Files` class contain two method one is private `_reports` which is get called in another method named as `get_file_data` but when i run my pytest it gives this error

> ***AttributeError: 'TestFiles' object has no attribute '_reports'***

here is my `TestFiles` class

```
import Files

class TestFiles:
    def test_generate_output_files(self):
        Files.get_file_data(self)
```

this is my `Files` class

```
class Files:

    def _reports(self):
        # does some work
        pass

    def get_file_data(self):
        reports = self._reports()
```

Comment: What do you mean by **private method**? Aside that, I htink you are importing the `Files class wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not creating a class - you're just calling the method. The `self` parameter will be the class object in that case, and you won't be able to access the private method on the class instance.

Instead you'll have to create the object and call the method on the object:

```
from Files import Files

class TestFiles:
    def test_generate_output_files(self):
        files_object = Files()
        files_object.get_file_data()
```

Comment: The call to `files_object.get_file_data(self)` will get a missing parameter because you are passing a parameter and the method definition hasn't left room for any (because its self parameter is the Files object).

Comment: Hello @MatsLindh I tried code you have provide but it giving me new error ```TypeError: get_file_data() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given```

Comment: Sorry, the `self` shouldn't be in the method call. I forgot to remove it from your test code in the question.